# Permissions to folder are changed to ??????? after mount

Tags: permissions, mount, nfs, fstab, suse

I was trying to mount folders from one system to another using "mount" and the following configuration in /etc/fstab

```
<systemX>:/h/shared /h/shared    nfs        rw,sync,user,auto      0 0 
<systemX>:/h/data /h/data        nfs        rw,sync,user,auto      0 0
<systemX>:/h/log /h/log          nfs        rw,sync,user,auto      0 0
```

and the same for the opposite one (Y). For each I did *chmod 777 -R*. 
I have those described in /etc/exports as:

```
/h/shared <systemX>(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
/h/data <systemX>(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
/h/log <systemX>(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

I did *exportfs -rv* and *mount -a*.
As a result I get:

```
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting (null)
```

and also after *ls -la*

```
ls: cannot access log: Permission denied
drwxrwxrwx  5 root root 4096 Aug  9 12:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 26 root root 4096 Aug 11 14:15 ..
d?????????  ? ?    ?       ?            ? data
d?????????  ? ?    ?       ?            ? log
d?????????  ? ?    ?       ?            ? shared
```

For each I got  *Stale file handle*.

Comment: ...Wait a moment. You're trying to mount X:/h/shared via NFS on Y:/h/shared, and then Y:/h/shared back again on X:/h/shared? _Why would you do that?_

Comment: Because I want to mount only those 3, not the others under /h